# Get Twitter id with Screen Name

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Hi I'm trying to get Twitter ID by Screen name..

```
Screen name is: KTutorials
```

Here is my link to get Twitter Id

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=ktutorials&count=5000
```

But I'm getting this error.

```
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Here is my Twitter link `https://twitter.com/ktutorials`

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using Twitter API to GET followers/ids method. GET request for this method require [OAuth Signature](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth). This means that you should have Twitter App created and if not, you should have create one [here](https://apps.twitter.com/app/new).

Subsequently, you should visit [GET followers/ids documentation page](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids), and get OAuth Signature using the "OAuth Signature Generator" located at bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

**Bad Authentication data** tells that you it can't do the operation due to the bad authentication.

> From API V1.1, all requests should be authenticated first. So, create
>   an app in Twitter console and put the important keys like Access keys
>   and Consumer keys.

If you feel you are authenticated user, then re-generate your token and give another try!